# change inija2 template file with jquery or javascript

Tags: html, jquery, jinja2

I have no idea how, but would like to know if it is possible to change the file in the jinja2 include statement.

such as:
{% include file.name %} to {% include file1.name %}

Since the file.name is in include parentheses, I could not use {{ file.name }} to achieve this.

Thought maybe I could use something like jquery,

```
$(".btnt").click(function(){
    $("section:fourth").replaceWith("{% include 'file1.name' %}");}
```

maybe initiate with button click, would this have to be on same page. I tend to use flask python for most projects.

Comment: JavaScript is client side, Jinja is server side (so, it happens before client-side), so, no, you cannot do it without an AJAX request, for example. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually used jinja2 to read variable to decide which file.name to use

```
{% if var %}
{% include file.name %}
{% else %}
{% include file1.name %}
{% endif %}
```

This checks var for true,  set from flask render template arguments.
If true uses file.name, if false uses file1.name

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is a technique which i use to transfer server side rendering to client side. it is basically returing json to the template itself directly. Like this:

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("a.html",dumps=json.dumps,data={"hello":"hello"})
```

`a.html`

```
<script>
    var jsonString = '{{dumps(data)}}'
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
</script>
```

This code should help you to use jinja in your scripts. But I recommend you to use APIs that return json data instead of this. For that you can use `$.getJSON` method.